# Keeping the same orientation with Auto Layout

Tags: ios, autolayout

How can I keep the orientation of a view completely unchanged when the interface orientation changes, independently from the other views?

For example, if I have a tall blue view in portrait mode, I would like the view to remain oriented the same way when the interface switches to landscape mode. If I have any other views aside from this view, the other views should reorient as usual, and, also, the status bar should get reoriented as well. The only view that should not get reoriented is this blue view.

[image: Expected behavior]

All I could do so far with Auto Layout was to resize and reorient the view, which is what I don't want to happen.

[image: Actual behavior]

Answer (score 0):

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate;
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations;
```

This should help you.

Also you may try to use

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:@(UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) forKey:@"orientation"];
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, if `shouldAutorotate` returns `NO`, then *none* of the views will rotate anymore. I would like the rest of the views to work as usual, and only keep this one view in the same orientation.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try overriding the NavigationController Class. 
In that, Implement the `supportedInterfaceOrientations` methods.

```
-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    UIViewController *vc = [[self viewControllers] lastObject];
Class clsSupportsSpecificOri = NSClassFromString(@"REQUIRED_CLASS");

if ([vc isKindOfClass:clsSupportsSpecificOrientation]))  {

    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft;//Set your required orientation

}
else {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}

}
```

This might helps you. As the `supportedInterfaceOrientation` method gets called every time a navigation occurs.